# How to reparent in Git

Tags: git

What non-interactive Git command(s) achieve the change from *Before* to *After* in each case?

**1a. Reparenting I**

Before:

```
A---B---C---D
```

After:

```
  C'---D'
 /
A---B
```

**1b. Reparenting II**

Before:

```
  C---D
 /
A---B
```

After:

```
  C
 /
A---B---D'
```

**1c. Reparenting III**

Before:

```
  C
 /
A---B---D
```

After:

```
  C---B'---D'
 /
A
```

Comment: Your questions sound like quiz questions ... are you sure you are allowed to simply ask on the internet?

Comment: Paul, what class even knows what version control is, let alone put git graph node samples on their tests?

Comment: *Quiz* does not necessarily have to be a class ... I don't know, but the question(s) simply have so little context that they really sounded like this.

Comment: why is a context necessary in this case? I deliberately broke the problem down in to the very specific operations I was trying to do.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

These all look like applications of `git rebase --onto`.

#### 1a. Reparenting I

Before:

```
A---B---C---D
```

After:

```
  C'---D'
 /
A---B
```

Set up branches to label the particular commits and then rebase onto.

1. `git checkout -b ex1a-b B`
2. `git checkout -b ex1a-d D`
3. `git checkout -b ex1a-a A`
4. `git rebase --onto ex1a-a ex1a-b ex1a-d`

#### 1b. Reparenting II

Before:

```
  C---D
 /
A---B
```

After:

```
  C
 /
A---B---D'
```

Creating branches is similar to the above: `git rebase --onto ex1b-b ex1b-c ex1b-d`.

#### 1c. Reparenting III

Before:

```
  C
 /
A---B---D
```

After:

```
  C---B'---D'
 /
A
```

Again with the branches, but now just `git rebase ex1c-c ex1c-d`.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on your definition of `B'`, `C'`, and `D'`.

If you want to move around *patches*, so that (in the first example) `git diff B C` == `git diff A C'`, then you want to "rebase" (not "reparent") using `git rebase` as described by [Emil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4982356/303425).

If, on the other hand, you want to move around *snapshots*, then you really do want to "reparent".  To do this, I suggest using [`git reparent`](https://github.com/MarkLodato/git-reparent).

Most likely, you actually want to rebase and not reparent, but for reference, here are the commands for reparenting.  They are somewhat complicated, because this is not a normal thing to do.

(The following assumes you are currently in a branch at D.)

**1a. Reparenting I**

```
git rebase -i B
# Select the "edit" command for C
git reparent -p A
git rebase --continue
```

**1b. Reparenting II**

```
git reparent -p B
```

**1c. Reparenting III**

```
git rebase -i A
# Select the "edit" command for B
git reparent -p C
git rebase --continue
```