# Change parent of a commit

Tags: git, merge, move, rebase, cherry-pick

I try to move a commit on top of another branch ignoring all changes done in target branch.

Current situation is:

```
      master
        ↓
--A--B--C
   \
    D--E
```

I want to move commit E in front of C

```
      master
        ↓
--A--B--C--E'
   \
    D--E
```

with E' being identical to E except parrent is C now instead of D (this means tree of E and E' should be identical).

To be more precides:

```
"git cat-file -p E" shows e.g.
tree b98c9a9f9501ddcfcbe02a9de52964ed7dd76d5a
parent D

"git cat-file -p E'" should show
tree b98c9a9f9501ddcfcbe02a9de52964ed7dd76d5a
parent C
```

I tried rebase with differnt parameters as well as cherry-pick but all of them finally try to merge any changes done in C into the new E' commit :(

Only solution preventing massive merge I found so far is

```
check out C
copy over all stuff from E to C
commit and get E'
```

Now the trees are identical and the parents are differnt but there must be a simpler and much faster way, since all that has to be done is creating a simple commit-object with existing tree-object.

Comment: [Using git-reparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981052/how-to-reparent-in-git/19143448#19143448) solves this problem directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yay, your diagram is accurate!

Alas, there's no obvious tool in Git to achieve the result you want.  The problem here is that rebase is just automated cherry-picking, and cherry-picking is about converting commits—and their snapshots—to change-sets and merging those changes with some other commit to make a new commit, which isn't want you want: you want to preserve the original snapshot.

Fortunately, there are several pretty-easy easy ways to do this.  Unfortunately, some of them use at least one *plumbing command*, i.e., a not-meant-for-users, not shiny porcelain, internal Git command.

First, let's note that your own solution is correct:

> Only solution preventing massive merge I found so far is
>
> ```
> check out C
> copy over all stuff from E to C
> commit and get E'
> ```

which in actual Git commands is, e.g.:

```
$ git checkout -b new-branch master
$ git rm -r .                     # in case there are files in C that aren't in E at all
$ git checkout <hash-of-E> -- .   # overwrite using E
$ git commit
```

This is actually not that bad, but it causes a lot of updates to the work-tree, which can be annoying if your next `make` takes an hour, or whatever.

#### Easier way #1

The first easier way to do this is:

```
$ git checkout -b new-branch master
$ git read-tree -u <hash-of-E>
$ git commit
```

The `read-tree` operation replaces your *index* contents with those taken from commit E.  The `-u` flag tells Git: *As you do this index update, update the work-tree too: if a file is removed entirely from the index, remove it from the work-tree too, or if a file is replaced in the index, replace it in the work-tree too.*  This flag is not actually required, because `git commit` is going to use what's in the index, but it's a good idea for sanity.

#### Easier way #2

The second easier method is this:

```
$ git commit-tree -p master -m "<message>" <hash-of-E>^{tree}
```

This *prints out* the new commit's hash ID; we then need to set something to point *to* this new hash ID:

```
$ git update-ref refs/heads/new-branch <hash-ID>
```

Or, in one line:

```
$ git update-ref refs/heads/new-branch $(git commit-tree -p master -m "<message>" <hash-of-E>^{tree})
```

Note that `-m "<message>"` can be replaced with `-F <file>` to read a message from a file, or even `-F -` to read a message from stdin.  You can then copy the commit message from commit `E` using `git log --no-walk --format=%B <hash-of-E>` and pipe that to the rest of the one-line command.

Be sure that `new-branch` really is a new branch name, or if not, that it's the branch you want to re-set and is not the current branch, because `git update-ref` does no error-checking by default.

#### Easier way #3

You can also do the job like this:

```
$ git checkout -b new-branch <hash-of-E>   # now at E, with E in index and work-tree
$ git reset --soft master                  # make new-branch identify C, without
                                           # touching index or work-tree
$ git commit -c <hash-of-E>                # make new commit using E's message
```

This last method has the least work-tree churn, so is perhaps the best of the three.  However, method #2 creates the new commit without touching *anything*, so if you don't actually *want* to be on the new branch, method #2 is perhaps the best.

Comment: Thanks a lot, especially #2 is what I had in mind :)

Just for completeness, I think there is an "m" missed in the command of #1
    _$ git read-tree -**m**u <hash-of-E>_
isn't it?

Comment: @Foobar: you *can* use `-m`. The result should act the same; the difference is (according to the documentation) just whether the stat info in the index is replaced.

Comment: Regarding easier way #1: I get the following error: `fatal: -u is meaningless without -m, --reset, or --prefix`